# Getting constant "(got 12 columns instead of 11)" error for numpy genfromtxt. I have tried the solutions from other posts but none of them work

Tags: python, numpy

[screenshot of data]

```
output_csv = np.genfromtxt(path, delimiter=',', filling_values=0, autostrip=True, skip_header=1,
                    dtype=({'names': ['sku_num', 'fiscl_wk', 'mkt_nbr', 'mkt_name', 'total_units', 'total_sales',
                                      'econ_cost', 'gm_dollars', 'gm_percent', 'retail', 'aur'],
                            'formats': [int, int, int, str, int, int, int, int, int, int, int]}))
```

my output is this every time and I defined the names and said to skip header. the header simply has those title that I am renaming.

```
ot 12 columns instead of 11)
Line #114182 (got 12 columns instead of 11)
Line #114186 (got 12 columns instead of 11)
Line #114191 (got 12 columns instead of 11)
Line #114201 (got 12 columns instead of 11)
Line #114217 (got 12 columns instead of 11)
```

What am I missing? I have tried using pandas first but it slows down the program (and doesnt work very well) and I also know this is supposed to work.

Comment: How big is this file? Reading a csv to df is usually quite fast in pandas?

Comment: its not that big, just 15mb

Comment: @tosin Can you post a sample of file, so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @tosin if it's not large, do you need super duper performance? If not, i would maybe rethink pandas, just for the sake of ease.

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin I just uploaded a screenshot of the data, didn't see where I could attach a file

Comment: Use `isecols=range(11)`.  It should then be able to read the longer lines without choking.  `invalid_raise=False` will let it skip the longer rows without raising an error.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you that worked, but it is noe erasing the str value and returning ' ' for the 4th column even though I formatted that one to come through as a string

Comment: What's the dtype for that column? '<U'?   That's a 0 length string.  You need to specify a string length, e.g 'U10'.  Or use `dtype=None` and let it deduce the right width.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much @hpaulj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy gives that error when it encounters a line of data that's longer than it was expecting. You specified 11 column names and 11 columns types, but the lines reported as having 12 columns instead of 11 have 11 commas in them. So when numpy is searching for the `,` delimiter it finds 12 entries rather than 11. You'll need to open the csv in some text editor and take a look at those lines.

Comment: will I have to do that for every csv I pull? Because that can get cumbersome.

Comment: Only if you want to use the numpy.genfromtxt function on your data without first pre-processing it. You can try the `invalid_raise = False` option explained in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html). That will just drop those problematic rows.

Comment: I dont think thats an option either, id be losing important data, but thank you